# TYPO3 - Previous and Next page

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a set of pages which are siblings in the pagetree. I have 2 links  to the next and previous page on top, and I want to add a class="prev" to the links that take you to the previous page, and "next" to the link that takes you to the next page. This is my code:

```
page.10.marks.MAIN.20 = HMENU
page.10.marks.MAIN.20{

    includeNotInMenu = 1
    excludeUidList = 78

    special = browse
    special{
        items = prev|next
    }

    1 = GMENU
    1 {
        wrap = <div class="ref-navi-wrapper clearfix">|</div>
        submenuObjSuffixes = a |*|  |*| b

        NO = 1
        NO {
            ATagParams = class="ref-nav prev" |*| |*| class="ref-nav next"
            ATagTitle.field = title

            altImgResource{
                width = 114
                import = uploads/media/
                import{
                    field = media
                    listNum = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that in the last page, since there is only one link to the previous page, it takes the class "next", not "prev".

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a condition and use {register:count_MENUOBJ}:

That means:

```
  ATagParams = class="ref-nav prev"
  ATagParams.override = class="ref-nav next"
  ATagParams.override {
    if.equals.dataWrap = {register:count_MENUOBJ}|
    if.value = 2
  }
```